# How to send ajax request from DMZ to Internal Secure Network?

Tags: python, ajax, dmz

When trying to send an ajax request from DMZ to Internal Local Network, I receive the error "Mixed Content: The page at 'URL' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint".
One solution found in Google was to add the SSL certificate to the computer where the web service is. However my web service is in the secure zone of the network (with no access to internet) so I cann't add the SSL certificate to it.
Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefor off-topic.

Comment: Why does being in the secure zone mean you can't add an SSL certificate to it?